# See GNOME Terminal output in virtual console

Tags: gnome-terminal

I've got a program running in a GNOME Terminal, but the screensaver is acting up and won't let me back in with my password. While waiting for a fix for [the gnome-screensaver bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/435928), is there some way to see the output (or even take over the process) in a virtual console (Ctrl-Alt-F1) without being able to interact with the GNOME Terminal?

Clarification: The original issue was the screensaver, but the question I'd like answered is how to see the output from a process running in another terminal, after starting the process without any logging to file. I'm guessing it should be possible to set the output device of a process from a different shell? Or is it possible to put a process in another shell into background mode, and get it into the foreground in the current shell? Or even ask GNOME Terminal to redirect or copy the output?

Comment: This was tagged as belong-on-superuser. I'm not convinced, but please don't use tags in this way. Leave a comment or flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had luck in the past killing the screensaver from a virtual console, unlocking X session.

```
# Get the pid (xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver, etc.)
ps -f -u $(whoami) | grep screensaver

kill -9 12345 # Replace 12345 with the real pid
```

**EDIT:** Seems like this has been thought of, and you should use one of these commands, depending on which screensaver program you use:

```
xscreensaver-command -exit
gnome-screensaver-comand --exit
```

See the man page for those commands for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way is to pipe the output to a file, like `program > program.log`
Do `tail -f program.log` in another tab of Gnome console, and the same in the non-X console.

Alternatively, use `tee` to duplicate the output in the same console: `program | tee program.log`

Answer (score 1):

ssh in to the box.  kill the screensaver. su to become root and kill -9 if it's really acting up.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Gnome-Terminal displays the output of one vty out of /dev. So just connect your console to that vty.

Comment: How do I figure out which device it's connected to?

Comment: dunno exactly, but with "ps -x" you can see "pts/X" in the second column, this should give you the hint, I'll take a research for this, too

Answer (score -1):

Launch program with `screen`.

Open another terminal, launch `screen -x` and you have two terminals acting like one. Try it, it's fun :)